# How to remove a particular marker from Google Map in Android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I add a marker on each map click, and I only want to see the last one.

I tried the following code:

```
if(marker!=null)
{
marker.visible(false);
marker=null;
}

marker=new MarkerOptions().position(latLng);
googleMap.addMarker(marker);
```

I see every marker even though I set it to invisible.

How can I remove after each click? I can't find any remove methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mention here in documentation  , `Remove()` method in Marker class will help you

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker#remove()

and here tutorial about adding and removing markers on map

http://www.jiahaoliuliu.com/2013/08/android-adding-and-removing-markets-on.html

Comment: Yes, you are right, I modified the marker option, not the marker itself. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Just keep a reference to the marker each time you do the click :

```
Marker marker = map.addMarker(MARKER_OPTIONS);
```

Then call `remove()` method :

```
marker.remove();
```

Comment: Yes, that is the way.

Comment: @Nestor if that solved your problem, don't forget to mark the answer as the correct one. have a good day !

Comment: Mohammed's answer is also correct, and he posted it first. Yours is good, too, but I can't mark both.

Comment: No problem :). Happy we have helped y ou.